# Intellij 2020.1 No available terminal and no project structure

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

I have installed Intellij 2020.1 from the Snap Store on Ubuntu 18.04.

The program seems fine except there is no available terminal. I've checked in two different projects, one in Kotlin and one in Scala. The in-program helps says it should be available via View > Tool Windows > Terminal   but there is no option for terminal there. I also tried the method of open file in terminal and nothing happened.  The program says terminal is bundled when I try to download a plugin. Also using help, it shows terminal and shows it is toggled on.  I would like to use both a terminal window for bash and one for sbt.

Another problem that I can more easily live with but is bothersome is there is no project/file structure on the left as with previous versions of Intellij I've used. When I click items in the path displayed above, it shows all the files, so they are there. I have found no option to get the folders and files on the left as most people are accustomed to.

Could this problem have originated because I used a version from the Snap Store? It would slow me down but I could install natively if there is a good chance that is the cause. Otherwise, I'm just missing something ?

It is very important I get up and rolling with some projects. All help appreciated.

Comment: Update1:  I just checked my Fedora machine with the same version of Intellij and all features are available, terminal, sbt shell and with project structure on the left.  So I plan to reinstall Intellij on my Ubuntu machine and will update.

Comment: Please check that "Terminal" plugin is enabled in "Settings | Plugins"

Comment: Update2:  Setting to default settings seems to have solved the problem. I wish I had a more interesting answer, but that's what did it.